# $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ is countable induction

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was trying to to prove $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ is countable,

If I let $f:\Bbb N \times \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ be given by $f((m,n))= m+\sum_{i=0}^{m+n-2}i$

then $f(1,1) = 1\\
     f(1,2) = 2\\
     f(2,1) = 3\\
     f(1,3) = 4\\
     f(2,2) = 5$

It keeps going this way.. so basically I want to prove it is a bijection using induction but I don't know how to proceed..

Comment: Do you only want to prove it by induction?

Comment: Or how about just finding an injection $f: \mathbb{N}$ X $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$

Comment: I don't see how you could use induction. What are you going to induct on? I think Prince M's idea is best.

Comment: induction on $k \in N$ saying.. P(k) is the statement that there exist $m,n \in N$ such that f((m,n)) = k and $m,n \in N$ are unique?

Comment: Idea: Justify that $\mathbb{N}$ X $\mathbb{N}$ is an infinite set. Justify that you have an $injection$ from $\mathbb{N}$ X $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. This proves that $\mathbb{N}$ X $\mathbb{N}$ is countable. There is a similar, but easier, map to choose than the one you came up with but you have the right idea.

Comment: Its not clear that f(m,n) is 1-1 into N, you would need to prove that each (m,n) maps to a unique value in N and that every member of N is reached.  If you want to use induction perhaps you can define the traversal of NxN, so given (m,n) what would the next pair be in the sequence, then that would define an bijection into N.